# how does tesseract choose character based on confidence?

Tags: c++, ocr, tesseract

I am using tesseract for ocr. At tesseract there is the possibilty to recognize text at different kind of levels, like recognize single words, lines, paragraphs, characters. There is also the possibility to get the confidence of each of these levels. So I took a look at the confidence and noticed that tesseract often returns not the highest confidence character as the best choice.Can someone please tell me how does tesseract choose the suitable character?
[for exemple for the character "l" it does not choose neither the highest confidence nor the lowest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kV5HV.png)